# Find the volume of the solid that results when the region enclosed by the given curves is revolved about the $y$-axis

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

> **Q**:Find the volume of the solid that results when the region enclosed by the given curves is revolved about the $y$-axis:
>   $$y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}}\:(x>0),x=0,y=0,y=2$$

My first problem is I can't imagine the region and the answer provided by the book is: $\pi \tan^{-1}2$ which is far away from what I figured out. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us your calculations.  It's hard to say what you're doing wrong if you don't show us what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the graph of the function (in red) with the area to be revolved around the $y$-axis shaded in blue.

There are two ways you could do this: by re-expressing the function in terms of $y$ and using the [disc method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration), or by leaving the function the way it is and using the [shell method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration).

Using the first method, you would need to evaluate the integral $$\pi\int_0^2[g(y)]^2dy,$$ where $g(y)$ is the same function, but expressed in terms of $y$ (in other words, $x=\ldots$ instead of $y=\ldots$).

To find the volume using the second method, you would need two integrals (can you tell why?): $$2\pi\int_0^ax(2)dx+2\pi\int_a^1xf(x)dx,$$ where $x=a$ is the point of intersection between the function and the line $y=2$, which I'll leave to you to calculate.

[image]

---

Here's a brief explanation of why I used two integrals in the second method:

The general formula for finding the volume of a solid of revolution with the shell method is $$2\pi\int_a^bxf(x)\,dx,$$ where $f(x)$ is some function that gives the height of the region you want to revolve around the $y$-axis. In this case, from $x=0$ to $x=1/\sqrt{5}$, that function is just $y=2$, while from $x=1/\sqrt{5}$ to $x=1$, the height is given by $y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}}$. Because the two regions have different heights, we need to use separate integrals to find the volume obtained from revolving each region around the $y$-axis.

In general, any time you see a sharp corner like the one at $(1/\sqrt{5},2)$, that's a sign that you'll need multiple integrals.

Comment: i need two integrals because you divides the volume into two cylinder at $\frac {1}{ \sqrt 5}$.Am i right?

Comment: From a geometrical standpoint, that's correct. Another way of asking the same question would be this: why would the integral $$2\pi\int_0^1xf(x)dx$$ not give you the right volume?

Comment: Really why? Can you explain it for me @Robert Howard Sir

Comment: Sure; I'll add an explanation to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Robert Howard Sir.Now I understand this question as well as this method :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The formula to compute volumes revolved about the $y$-axis is
$$V=2\pi\int_a^bxf(x)dx.$$

First check where $f(x)=2$:
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}}=2\implies 1-x^2=4x^2\implies x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

So you can integrate between $0$ and $1/\sqrt{5}$ with $g(x)=2$ and the rest of the area from $1/\sqrt{5}$ to $1$ with your function $f(x)$, you get
$$V=2\pi\int_0^{1/\sqrt{5}}xg(x)dx+2\pi\int_{1/\sqrt{5}}^1xf(x)dx=2\pi\int_0^{1/\sqrt{5}}2xdx+2\pi\int_{1/\sqrt{5}}^1x\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}}dx.$$

Comment: Why $V=\int_a^b \pi f(y)^2 dy$ this formula is not used by you @james watt Sir.

Comment: That formula is used to calculate volumes around the $x$-axis. If you rotate your function around $x$-axis the value $f(x)$ is the radius of your solid in a certain $x\in[a,b]$, integrating on $[a,b]$ you get the total volume. $f(x)$ is squared because the formula of the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$, in this case $r=f(x)$.